# Matplotlib not working after successful installation on Mountain Lion

Tags: python, matplotlib, osx-mountain-lion

I installed all the dependencies listed on [the matplotlib website](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html). However, it still doesn't work. I listed the python stack trace and installed python packages below. So, how can I solve this problem?

Python stack trace:

```
>>> import pylab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pylab.py", line 229, in <module>
    import matplotlib.finance
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/finance.py", line 37, in <module>
    from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection, PolyCollection
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 26, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 54, in <module>
    import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 18, in <module>
    import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1354, in <module>
    _rebuild()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1339, in _rebuild
    fontManager = FontManager()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 987, in __init__
    self.ttffiles = findSystemFonts(paths) + findSystemFonts()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 316, in findSystemFonts
    for f in get_fontconfig_fonts(fontext):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 280, in get_fontconfig_fonts
    for line in output.split('\n'):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 16560: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Installed python packages:

```
>$ pip freeze
PyRSS2Gen==1.0.0
Twisted==12.0.0
altgraph==0.9
bdist-mpkg==0.4.4
bonjour-py==0.3
macholib==1.4.2
matplotlib==1.4.x
modulegraph==0.9.1
nose==1.3.0
numpy==1.7.1
py2app==0.6.3
pyOpenSSL==0.13
pyobjc-core==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-Automator==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-CalendarStore==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-CoreData==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-CoreText==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-InterfaceBuilderKit==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-Message==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-PubSub==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-QTKit==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-Quartz==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-ServerNotification==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-SyncServices==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-WebKit==2.3.2a0
pyobjc-framework-XgridFoundation==2.3.2a0
pyparsing==2.0.1
python-dateutil==2.1
scipy==0.12.0
six==1.4.1
stevedore==0.11
tornado==3.1.1
virtualenv==1.10.1
virtualenv-clone==0.2.4
virtualenvwrapper==4.1.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
xattr==0.6.2
zope.interface==3.5.1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in matplotlib 1.4.x where `fontmanager.py` is trying to import a font whose name contains a non-ascii character.

Your question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689854/enthought-matplotlib-problems-with-plot-function/18690353#18690353) but the patch given won't help you because you have matplotlib 1.4.x installed and not 1.3.0.

As suggested in the question above, you can take a look at your font list and try removing fonts with non ascii characters. Look especially for `Æ`.

Or, you can try upgrading to the development version of matplotlib where it seems to be [fixed](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/bd191d50823b8797c765d86e227e4ca4f8595c31):

```
pip install git+https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git#egg=matplotlib-dev
```