# Enthought - matplotlib (problems with plot() function)

Tags: python, unicode, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to use [matplotlib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matplotlib) on Canopy Express. Even simple code does not run...

NOTE: the system does not recognize the `plot(x)` function. It seems there is something with ASCII X Unicode. My computer uses Unicode English(US).

From the console we have:

```
 C:\Users\dafonseca\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py in createFontList(fontfiles, fontext)
        582                 continue
        583             try:
    --> 584                 prop = ttfFontProperty(font)
        585             except KeyError:
        586                 continue

C:\Users\dafonseca\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py in ttfFontProperty(font)
        396         sfnt2 = ''
        397     if sfnt4:
    --> 398         sfnt4 = sfnt4.decode('ascii').lower()
        399     else:
        400         sfnt4 = ''

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)'

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    x = np.linspace(0, 10)
    line, = plt.plot(x, np.sin(x), '--', linewidth=2)
    dashes = [10, 5, 100, 5] # 10 points on, 5 off, 100 on, 5 off
    line.set_dashes(dashes)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2362) in matplotlib 1.3.0 that relates to having a non-ASCII character in one of your font names (possibly the `Æ` character).

You can either find and remove the offending font (the best idea) or try to patch your installation using the following procedure:

Open the following in a text editor:

`\Users\dafonseca\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site- packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py`

Search for `sfnt4 = sfnt4.decode('ascii').lower()`

And replace with `sfnt4 = sfnt4.decode('ascii', 'ignore').lower()`

Note that this bug won't exist in the next release of matplotlib.

Comment: I replace my code with 'ignore' solution.. It is working now.. Amazing!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution! :)