# IPython - mathplotlib does not render

Tags: python, ipython

Just installed IPython, and in using the notebook examples, the matplotlib graph example just prints out:

> matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x61bc850

Instead of drawing the graph. The example code I'm trying out is here:

> http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_examples/pylab_examples/integral_demo.py

And it is supposed to draw out a graph when you evaluate the cell.

How do I get it to draw the graph in the cell?

### Additional info:

Using Enthought Canopy / Win 7, updated to latest version.
I applied the patch to matplotlib described here:

> [Enthought - matplotlib (problems with plot() function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689854/enthought-matplotlib-problems-with-plot-function)
>   Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you have all of the code in the cell? The final line `show()` is what plots the graph, if it's missing you won't see anything.

Comment: The show() line is there as the final line.

Comment: How did you start the notebook? I start mine using `ipyhon notebook --pylab=inline`. Perhaps you've forgotten the `=inline` argument?

Comment: I am running inside Enthought Canopy, and imported that code using magic: %load http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_examples/pylab_examples/integral_demo.py

Comment: Try running `%matplotlib inline` in the notebook before you run that code.

Comment: Thomas, I get the error:    
   ERROR: Line magic function `%matplotlib` not found.    
When I try that