# pandas plot doesn't show in ipython notebook as inline

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, plot, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to plot graph in ipython notebook inline, but `.plot()` methos just shows the object information, as

```
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x10d8740d0>
```

but no graph. also i could make it show graph with `plt.show()`, but i want do it inline. so i tryed `%matplotlib inline` and `ipython notebook --matplotlib=inline`, but it was no helpful.

If i use `%matplotlib inline`,  then `.plot()` shows

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py:239: 
FormatterWarning: Exception in image/png formatter: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128) FormatterWarning,
```

and using `ipython notebook --matplotlib=inline` shows same.

Comment: Think we will need more info, show your code, imports and platform...

Comment: The error you described when using `% matplotlib inline` is due to an issue dealing with unicode and strings. Probably, you have characters encoded with `latin-1` and a conversion is trying to use `decode`. However, `decode` is converting your character to unicode using the default encoding `ascii` and since that character is not found in ascii, the conversion fails. You should try to convert your string to unicode using decode (`"\xe2".decode(encoding='latin-1')`) before passing that data to matplotlib.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
ipython notebook --matplotlib=inline
```

to

```
ipython notebook --matplotlib inline
```

Notice no `=` sign.

Answer (score 3):

I will give you an example based on my comment above:

You have something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

legend = "\xe2"

plt.plot(range(5), range(5))
plt.legend([legend])
```

which results in:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

As I said, this is because matplotlib wants to use strings of type `unicode`. So, in the process of plotting, matplotlib tries to decode your string to convert it to unicode using `decode`. However, `decode` has `ascii` as default encoding, and since your character doesn't belong to `ascii`, an error is shown. The solution is to decode the string yourself with the appropriate encoding:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

legend = "\xe2".decode(encoding='latin-1')

plt.plot(range(5), range(5))
plt.legend([legend])
```

[image]

By the way, regarding the use `ipython notebook --matplotlib inline`, it is considered bad practice to do that because you are hiding what you did in order to obtain the resulting notebook. It is much better to include `%matplotlib inline` in your notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your helps.
i've tried all of above, but did't work.

here i found that was bug in `fontmanager.py` in matplotlib 1.4.x, fixed with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643417/matplotlib-not-working-after-successful-installation-on-mountain-lion) development version of matplotlib and it worked.

i'm so sorry that i couldn't find it earlier. thanks for all of you.